# How to make iterated function calculate more quickly?

Tags: functions

[image: my mathematica note]

This iterated function calculate too slowly,could you look for another method?Thank you!

Comment: Code firstly,but not just screenshot,please.

Comment: In the code it looks like it says `* [an[k]]`. Is it supposed to be floor or ceiling?

Comment: sorry,I forget to add an[0]=1.

Comment: Please post copyable code, not a screenshot.  Make sure that if people copy and paste your code into a new notebook, it will run as you intended it, and it demonstrates the problem you are talking about.

Comment: Are you sure you do not want to give definition of `Z` `Sn`, `Tn`, `Un`? If not, it is expected to be slow, because even for small `n`, the result is a big symbolic expansion.

Answer (score 2):

The code as it stands evaluates rapidly:

```
an[n_] := an[n] = -1/Z[n] Sum[((k + α) * (k + α - 1) * Sn[n - k] +
                              (k + α)*Tn[n - k] + Un[n - k])*an[k], {k, 0, n - 1}]

an[200]
```

> 0

However, if the problem is not just a syntax error, the way to speed up a computation like would probably be about rewriting the code using `Fold` or `Nest`.

Comment: an[0]=1.Could you tell me how to rewrite the code using Nest?Thank you!

Comment: @smallice Try to evaluate `an[n]` for small `n`. You'll notice exponential growth of the expression, which apparently cant be simplified noticeably. Hence you shouldn't do the computation before all symbols are numerically known.